# ¿Cómo acceder a variables static desde otra clase en c++?

Tags: c++, variables, qt

Tengo este código implementado en **c++** usando el IDE Qt Creator:

```
static ArbolBB bb = ArbolBB();
```

Con esto creo una estructura binaria de búsqueda.

El problema es que esa declaración la tengo para usarlo en `mainwindows.ui`, en su archivo `mainwindows.cpp` y además esa misma variable `bb` la necesito usar en otra `windows.ui', también para su archivo .cpp correspondiente, para no perder la instancia y seguir usando las operaciones de un árbol bb.

He estado intentando algunas formas para utilizar la variable bb con static, primero declarándola en al `mainwindows.cpp`, como describo arriba, y tratando de acceder desde la otra ui con:

```
static ArbolBB bb2 = MainWindows::bb;
```

Tratando de lograr que de esta forma se solucione, pero veo que no funciona de tal manera.

Mi pregunta básicamente se resume a ¿Cómo acceder a variables static que declaré en el mainwinodows.cpp en el otro archivos windows.cpp?

O mejor aún, si me pueden explicar mejor cómo funciona lo del static en c++, y algunas formas comunes de utilizarlos.

Para empezar este es mi archivo uieliminar.cpp que genera la interfaz gráfica

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "instanciaarbole.h"

static ArbolBB bb1 = MainWindows::bb; //Acá quiero agregar la primera instancia

uiEliminar::uiEliminar(QWidget *parent) :

    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::uiEliminar)    
{  //Resto de código }
```

Con este otro método que se genera automáticamente de un boton intento utilizar la misma instancia que he generado en mi otro archivo.

```
void uiEliminar::on_btn_Eliminar_clicked()
{
    bb1.eliminarDato(dato);
    this->close();
}
```

### El archivo anterior es la segunda interfaz gráfica, de acá quiero usar la instancia de ArbolBB de la primera interfaz.

Ese otro archivo es:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "cliente_proveedor.h"
#include "arbolbb.h"
#include "uieliminar.h"
#include "instanciaarbole.h"

static ArbolBB bb = ArbolBB();



    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{    
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Listo");
}
```

Así sería la estructura de la parte superior.

Y acá un ejemplo de cómo lo uso en mi archivo del MainWindows

```
void MainWindow::on_actionMostrar_rbol_triggered()
{
    if(ui->rbtnArbolBB->isChecked()){           
           bb.mostrarEstructuraArbolBB();
    }else if(ui->rdBtnArbolAVL->isChecked()){

    }
}
```

Acá no tengo problemas porque es en este archivo donde hago la instancia. El problema viene cuando intento usar este objeto en el otro archivo (el que adjunté primeramente) para poder continuar con la misma estructura de datos.

Comment: Creo que tienes la suficiente reputación para saber que en problemas: *mi código no funciona* debes proveer un [mcve], por otro lado decir: *pero veo que no funciona de tal manera.* es muy genérico, para mi podria significar el código no compila, el código me lanza una excepción, podrias precisar el significado, por otro lado yendo al mundo de Qt, ¿ArbolBB hereda de una clase de Qt?, Qt tiene ciertas restricciones que quizas generen ese comportamiento.

Answer (score 4):

Tu problema no es que tu objeto sea `static`, tu problema es que quieres acceder a ese objeto desde diferentes [unidades de traducción [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (UdT), hay varias maneras de conseguirlo:

---

#### Variable externa (`extern`).

Una manera de conseguir el efecto que buscas es declarar tu variable `bb` en un archivo de cabecera:

`Arbol_Binario_Global.hpp`

```
#include "ArbolBB.hpp"

ArbolBB bb = ArbolBB{};
```

En cada archivo que incluyas `"Arbol_Binario_Global.hpp"` obtendrás acceso a la instancia `bb`. El problema es que según cómo uses esta cabecera puedes romper la ["*Regla de definición única*" [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) ya que las declaraciones cuentan también como definiciones (si no hay definición previa). Además no tardarás en darte cuenta que en cada UdT el contenido de `bb` variará; esto se debe a que en cada una de ellas estás usando una instancia diferente pero con igual nombre. Para evitar esto debes separar la definición de la declaración y marcar la definición como `extern`:

`Arbol_Binario_Global.hpp`

```
class ArbolBB; // Pre-declaracion

extern ArbolBB bb;
```

`Arbol_Binario_Global.cpp`

```
#include "ArbolBB.hpp"

ArbolBB bb = ArbolBB{};
```

Para que un objeto `extern` funcione adecuadamente, debe tener todas sus definiciones marcadas como `extern` excepto una; con este objeto marcado como `extern`, cualquier inclusión de la cabecera `Arbol_Binario_Global.hpp` hará conocer al compilador que existe un objeto llamado `bb` cuya definición debe buscar en otro lado, de esta manera todas las instancias de `bb` serán la misma en todas las UdT.

#### Función de acceso.

De manera parecida a la variable externa, puedes crear una cabecera que contenga una función que te devuelva tu instancia:

`Arbol_Binario_Global.hpp`

```
class ArbolBB; // Pre-declaracion

ArbolBB &AccederAlArbol();
```

En todas las UdT en que incluyas `"Arbol_Binario_Global.hpp"` podrás acceder a la instancia del árbol así:

`uieliminar.cpp`

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <QMessageBox>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "instanciaarbole.h"
#include "Arbol_Binario_Global.hpp"

ArbolBB &bb = AccederAlArbol();

uiEliminar::uiEliminar(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::uiEliminar)    
{  /*Resto de código*/ }
```

Para que funcione, tu archivo de código deberá ser así:

`Arbol_Binario_Global.cpp`

```
#include "ArbolBB.hpp"
#include "Arbol_Binario_Global.cpp"

ArbolBB &AccederAlArbol()
{
    static ArbolBB bb = ArbolBB{};
    return bb;
}
```

En este contexto, el cualificador `static` significa "*haz que sólo exista una instancia de esta variable*". Así que la primera vez que llames a `AccederAlArbol` se creará la instancia `bb` y las subsiguientes usarán dicha instancia, eso se conoce como [inicialización perezosa [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization).

Answer (score 3):

Tienes a tu disposición varias opciones:

**Mover la variable a un espacio común**

Lo recomendable sería que la variable no fuese global, sino incorporar un método de lectura (y otro de escritura, si procede). Estos métodos sí serían globales:

utilidad.h

```
#ifndef UTILIDAD_H
#define UTILIDAD_H

class ArbolBB;

ArbolBB& GetArbol();

#endif // UTILIDAD_H
```

utilidad.cpp

```
#include "utilidad.h"
#include "arbolbb.h"

static ArbolBB arbol;

ArbolBB& GetArbol()
{
  return arbol;
}
```

La ventaja de esta solución es que el acceso a la variable se hace mediante la función `GetArbol()`. Esto te permite saber quien accede a la variable en cada momento (mediante un *breakpoint*, un log, etc...), lo que permite detectar facilmente accesos no deseados y, si se hace necesario, incluso mecanismos de sincronismo (si se empiezan a usar hilos).

**Usar `extern`**

Como norma general se dice que las variables globales declaradas en archivos de implementación no son visibles fuera de dicho archivo y es cierto... a medias. El modificador `extern` permite acceder a dichas variables, aunque es una solución que tiene sus riesgos (si existen dos variables con el mismo nombre... a cual tendremos acceso???)

Así, el archivo `MainWindow.cpp` quedaría tal que:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "cliente_proveedor.h"
#include "arbolbb.h"
#include "uieliminar.h"
#include "instanciaarbole.h"

extern bb arbol;

// ...
```

Aunque yo, sinceramente, sigo recomendando la primera solución.

Answer (score -1):

Aquí el problema es porque defines al objeto con la palabra reservada `static`. C++ al ser hijo de C, hereda ciertas caracteristicas de este, en C, cuando defines una variable global de manera estatica, contienes esa variable a solo ese archivo en particular, miralo como una variable privada de ese archivo, la variable `bb1` esta contenida a ese ambito, a solo ese archivo. En resumen, quitale el `static`. Ademas las variables estaticas son las primeras a las que se les asigna memoria por el compilador, y no se les quita si no hasta el final de la ejecición del programa.

Ahora, `static` en C++ tiene otro significado, esta indica una instancia de la clase, cuando defines una variable u objeto dentro de una *clase* de manera estatica la convierte en una instancia de la *clase*, estas variables u objetos no pueden ser llamados por un objeto instanciado de esa clase, solo pueden ser utilizadas por otra función también estatica dentro de esa clase o de manera directa, así `Clase::variable`.

Comment: Entonces, ¿Cómo debería usar el código para poder utilizar la instancia de ArbolBB de primera interfaz en la segunda?

Comment: Prueba quitandole es `static`